# adding blocks in Presento beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes, block

I wish to add blocks in [Presento](https://github.com/RatulSaha/presento) beamer theme. I am not able to get the frame around the blocks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{config/presento} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \begin{block}{Observation 1} 
    Simmons Hall is composed.
  \end{block}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Observation 2}
    Simmons Dormitory is composed of brick.
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{Conclusion}
    Simmons Hall $\not=$ Simmons Dormitory.
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

How I would use the standard blocks in Presento beamer theme as in other themes like Madrid etc. What line should add/remove in the `.sty` file to get the frames around the standard blocks(like alert, example and basic block.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where can we find this theme?

Comment: https://github.com/RatulSaha/presento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes are already there, but their colour is invisible. To make them visible, you can for example use `\usecolortheme{orchid}` to get the colours used in many of the standard themes.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{presento} 

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\begin{block}{Observation 1} Simmons Hall is composed.
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}{Observation 2}
Simmons Dormitory is composed of brick.
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{alertblock}{Conclusion}
Simmons Hall $\not=$ Simmons Dormitory.
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

[image]